# Using Sha256 or Rfc2898DeriveBytes to create IC

Tags: c#, encryption, sha256

Based on this: http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/symmetric-encryption-in-c-sharp.aspx

I have written encryption/decryption of byte-arrays:

```
public static byte[] EncryptFile(string password, byte[] bytes, string salt)
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged aesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            DeriveBytes rgb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt));
            byte[] rgbKey = rgb.GetBytes(aesEncryption.KeySize >> 3);
            byte[] rgbIV = rgb.GetBytes(aesEncryption.BlockSize >> 3);
            aesEncryption.KeySize = 256;
            aesEncryption.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aesEncryption.IV = rgbIV;
            aesEncryption.Key = rgbKey;
            using (ICryptoTransform crypto = aesEncryption.CreateEncryptor())
            {
                return crypto.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }

    public static byte[] DecryptFile(string password, byte[] bytes, string salt)
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged aesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            DeriveBytes rgb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt));
            byte[] rgbKey = rgb.GetBytes(aesEncryption.KeySize >> 3);
            byte[] rgbIV = rgb.GetBytes(aesEncryption.BlockSize >> 3);
            aesEncryption.KeySize = 256;
            aesEncryption.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aesEncryption.IV = rgbIV;
            aesEncryption.Key = rgbKey;
            using (ICryptoTransform crypto = aesEncryption.CreateDecryptor())
            {
                return crypto.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

But when calculating the IV and the key, should I instead use SHA256 instead of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`?

Comment: So you copied some random code off the Internet and want us to tell you if it does the right thing?

Comment: The answer is no, btw. You should use Rfc2898DeriveBytes when you need to derive keys from a password, not SHA256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you should not use SHA256, SHA256 is a hashing function where `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is used to implements password-based key derivation functionality.

A hash function can be used to verify data, where the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is used specifically to generate a key.

Via msdn [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx)  and [SHA256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256.aspx)